# Unable to install Realtek rtl8723de drivers? (networking)

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, realtek-wireless

I am unable to install drivers.
I used these instructions:

```
git clone https://github.com/smlinux/rtl8723de.git -b 4.11-up
dkms add ./rtl8723de
dkms install rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414
depmod -a
reboot
```

But get this error:

```
$ sudo dkms install rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
'make' all KVER=5.0.0-23-generic.....(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8723de: 5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.0.0-23-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/make.log for more information.
```

I will reinstall Kubuntu 18.04, can anyone please give me step by step instructions to install the driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you reinstall 18.04, which uses kernel version 4.15-xx, then the step-by-step instructions will differ from this answer. This answer assumes that you remain with 19.04 using kernel version 5.0-xx:

```
git clone https://github.com/smlinux/rtl8723de.git -b 5.0-up
sudo dkms add ./rtl8723de
sudo dkms install rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414
sudo depmod -a
```

Reboot.

Comment: hello i have one question do i need to install linux headers before doing these instructions if yes how do i do it? thanks for relpying

Comment: Linux-headers is likely already installed. Confirm: `sudo dpkg -s linux-headers-generic` It should report: Status: install ok installed. Note that you also need to have build-essential installed. Confirm: `sudo dpkg -s build-essential` It appears, from above, that you already have git and dkms installed.